# how to modify c# array in c++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, dll

I've got an unmanaged C++ dll with a C-style exported function I'm trying to use from within C# code. The function is supposed to take arrays as arguments and modify them so I can use the results in C#.

So I figured out how to do this with float arrays. When my C function looks as follows...

```
__declspec( dllexport ) float testArrayFlt( const float *f, int arraySize, float *fCopy )
{
    float sum = 0.0f;

    for( int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++ )
    {
        sum += f[i];
        fCopy[i] = f[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

...then I have to declare as follows in C#:

```
[DllImport( lib )]
public static extern float testArrayFlt( float[] f, int arraySize, float[] fCopy );
```

Now, when I use it like this, everything works well:

```
float[] flt = new float[10];
float[] fltCopy = new float[flt.Length];
for( int i = 0; i < flt.Length; i++ )
    flt[i] = i;

float f = testArrayFlt( flt, flt.Length, fltCopy );

Console.WriteLine( "flt sum: " + f );
for( int i = 0; i < fltCopy.Length; i++ )
    Console.WriteLine( "flt #" + i + ": " + fltCopy[i] );
```

The output I get from that is:

> flt sum: 45
>
> flt #0: 0
>
> flt #1: 1
>
> flt #2: 2
>
> flt #3: 3
>
> flt #4: 4
>
> flt #5: 5
>
> flt #6: 6
>
> flt #7: 7
>
> flt #8: 8
>
> flt #9: 9

Now, when I try to do this with a Vector type, which is composed of three floats, only half of it works. Passing and reading the data, as well as returning results works, but not the modification of the passed array. In more detail: I got a C function as follows:

```
__declspec(dllexport) glm::vec3 testArrayVec3( const glm::vec3 *points, int arraySize, glm::vec3 *pointsCopy )
{
    glm::vec3 sum( 0.0f );

    for( int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++ )
    {
        sum += points[i];
        pointsCopy[i] = points[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

where glm::vec3 is basically just a struct of three floats. In C#, I define a counterpart

```
struct Vec3f
{
    public float X;
    public float Y;
    public float Z;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "[" + this.X + ", " + this.Y + ", " + this.Z + "]";
    }
};
```

...declare the dll import as...

```
[DllImport( lib )]
public static extern Vec3f testArrayVec3( Vec3f[] points, int arraySize, Vec3f[] pointsCopy );
```

...and use it as follows:

```
Vec3f[] points = new Vec3f[10];
Vec3f[] pointsCopy = new Vec3f[points.Length];
for( int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++ )
    points[i].X = points[i].Y = points[i].Z = i;

Vec3f p = testArrayVec3( points, points.Length, pointsCopy );

Console.WriteLine( "vec sum: " + p );
for( int i = 0; i < pointsCopy.Length; i++ )
    Console.WriteLine( "vec #" + i + ": " + pointsCopy[i] );
```

Now I get the following output:

> vec sum: [45, 45, 45]
>
> vec #0: [0, 0, 0]
>
> vec #1: [0, 0, 0]
>
> vec #2: [0, 0, 0]
>
> vec #3: [0, 0, 0]
>
> vec #4: [0, 0, 0]
>
> vec #5: [0, 0, 0]
>
> vec #6: [0, 0, 0]
>
> vec #7: [0, 0, 0]
>
> vec #8: [0, 0, 0]
>
> vec #9: [0, 0, 0]

What confuses me is, that it can't be *that* far from being right, since calculation and returning of the sum does works. It just seems like the second array isn't passed properly by reference, but I can't find out how to do that. Also, in the float-version it works just like that. I also checked in the dll, the glm::vec3 assignment *does* work, so pointsCopy actually *does* contain the correct data after the loop, but it doesn't arrive on the C#-side.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using an unsafe block in C# and passing the array as a pointer to the C++ DLL?

Comment: Hmh. You're right, it does work with unsafe code. Thanks! It's still weird, though. I can live with this for now, but ultimately, I'd prefer a solution without unsafe code. I mean, it should work like this, shouldn't it?

Comment: *"it should work like this, shouldn't it?"* - No, obviously not. In C++ the address of an object must not change throughout the object's lifetime. In .NET this happens all the time. So why should this work? At any rate, if you need to interop with unmanaged code, use C++/CLI.

Comment: There are multiple possible problems, first of all the values are not pinned in memory, meaning their location changes. At one point it might work, but when the garbage collector comes by, you're using an invalid pointer. Another problem is that an array in C# is nothing like an array in C++, for example it contains information on its size, which is also stored in memory somewhere. The binary layouts are not compatible.

Comment: @IInspectable I thought that it should work since it also works with an array of floats and in my case I got an array of structs, which, to my knowledge, are also value-types. So why whould the addresses of my structs move while the addresses of my floats don't? Obviously, I'm not an expert in C#, so it's a bit confusing to me. Thanks for the hint, I'll have a closer look into C++/CLI.

Comment: @Shadowwolf Thanks for your reply. I know a C# array is more than just the data, but still, with an unsafe block and a fixed statement like `fixed( float* pfc = &pointsCopy[0].X )` it works. Now, this type of syntax also doesn't account for the C# array overhead, it just looks like plain C and doesn't seem to care for the layout. For that reason I expect the compiler taking care about these things for me.

Comment: What matters here is whether the pinvoke marshaller considers the argument *blittable*.  If it is then it can simply pin the array and pass the pointer, your C code is writing directly into the managed object.  Apparently it doesn't, I'm not sure why.  You then have to be explicit that you want the array content to be copied back.  use `[In, Out] Vec3f[] pointsCopy`.  Using `fixed` is a hack to defeat the marshaller but it is pretty dangerous, GC heap corruption is a bug you'll be hunting for a month.

Comment: @HansPassant Works like a charm, that's the answer I was hoping for - `fixed` seemed like a hack to me. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Good.  You still need to find out why it isn't blittable, it isn't normal.  Please remove the ToString() method.